# polars dropna equivalent on list of columns

Tags: dataframe, python-polars

I'm a new polars user. Pandas has [df.dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html). I need to replace this functionality, but I haven't found a dropna in polars. Searching for `drona` currently yields no results in the Polars User Guide.

My specific problem: convert the following statement from pandas to polars

`df.dropna(subset=list_of_vars, thresh=1)`

I think I should use `df.filter`. I do not know a-priori what will be in `list_of_vars`, so making a set of `|` filters is a bit tricky. all vars in `list_of_vars` are columns in the dataframe

input

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        'col1':[0,float('nan'),2,3],
        'col2':[0,float('nan'),float('nan'),3],
        'col3':[0,1,2,3],
        'col3':[float('nan'),float('nan'),float('nan'),float('nan')]
    }
)
df
list_of_vars = ['col1', 'col2']
```

Desired output:

Keep only rows in the dataframe where the value of at least one of the columns in `list_of_vars` is not NaN/null.

```
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2 ┆ col3 ┆ col4 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ i64  ┆ f64  │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 0.0  ┆ 0.0  ┆ 0    ┆ NaN  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2.0  ┆ NaN  ┆ 2    ┆ NaN  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3.0  ┆ 3.0  ┆ 3    ┆ NaN  │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

In this case, rows with a good value from col1 or col2 are retained. Row 3, with a good value only from col3, is dropped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let's expand the data to include `null` values in Polars, so that we can show how to filter both `null` and `NaN` if you need to.  (You can always change the logic below if you don't need it.)

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        'col1':[0,float('nan'),2,3, None],
        'col2':[0,float('nan'),float('nan'),3, None],
        'col3':[0.0,1,2,3,4],
        'col4':[float('nan'),float('nan'),float('nan'),float('nan'), 5]
    }
)
df
```

```
shape: (5, 4)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2 ┆ col3 ┆ col4 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64  │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 0.0  ┆ 0.0  ┆ 0.0  ┆ NaN  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ NaN  ┆ NaN  ┆ 1.0  ┆ NaN  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2.0  ┆ NaN  ┆ 2.0  ┆ NaN  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3.0  ┆ 3.0  ┆ 3.0  ┆ NaN  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ null ┆ null ┆ 4.0  ┆ 5.0  │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

##### Specifically: `df.dropna(subset=list_of_vars, thresh=1)`

> Keep only rows in the dataframe where the value of at least one of the columns in list_of_vars is not NaN/null.

If we're looking to drop both `null` values and `NaN` values in Polars, we can do this in a single filter step.  (For comparison, I'll also include the result from Pandas.)

```py
list_of_vars = ['col1', 'col2']
thresh = 1
df.filter(
    pl.sum(
        pl.col(list_of_vars).is_not_null() & pl.col(list_of_vars).is_not_nan()
    ) >= thresh
)

df.to_pandas().dropna(subset=list_of_vars, thresh=thresh)
```

```
shape: (3, 4)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2 ┆ col3 ┆ col4 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64  │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 0.0  ┆ 0.0  ┆ 0.0  ┆ NaN  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2.0  ┆ NaN  ┆ 2.0  ┆ NaN  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3.0  ┆ 3.0  ┆ 3.0  ┆ NaN  │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
>>> df.to_pandas().dropna(subset=list_of_vars, thresh=thresh)
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0   0.0   0.0   0.0   NaN
2   2.0   NaN   2.0   NaN
3   3.0   3.0   3.0   NaN
```

And for threshold of 2:

```
shape: (2, 4)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2 ┆ col3 ┆ col4 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64  │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 0.0  ┆ 0.0  ┆ 0.0  ┆ NaN  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3.0  ┆ 3.0  ┆ 3.0  ┆ NaN  │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
>>> df.to_pandas().dropna(subset=list_of_vars, thresh=thresh)
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0   0.0   0.0   0.0   NaN
3   3.0   3.0   3.0   NaN
```

We're using [`polars.sum`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.sum.html) to summarize row-wise the boolean values produced from the `is_not_null` and `is_not_nan` Expressions.

##### More generally: a prototype `dropna` method

> Pandas has df.dropna. I need to replace this functionality, but I haven't found a dropna in polars.

If you need to, we can create a `dropna` function that will work on DataFrames and LazyFrames directly.  If this is more than you want/need, you can just skip this and use the code in the section above.

Here's some prototype code for a `dropna` for LazyFrames.  It's a bit complex, but you should be able to copy/paste this into a module and call it directly on a LazyFrame, as well as tweak the logic to your needs.

```py
from typing import Sequence
import polars.internals.lazy_functions as pl_lazy
import polars.datatypes as datatypes
import polars.internals as pli
from polars.internals.lazyframe.frame import LDF
from polars.internals.dataframe.frame import DF


def dropna(
    self: LDF,
    how: str = 'any',
    thresh: int = None,
    subset: str | Sequence[str] = None,
) -> LDF:
    """
    Remove null and NaN values
    """

    if subset is None:
        subset = pli.all()
    else:
        subset = pli.col(subset)

    if thresh is not None:
        result = (
            self
            .filter(
                pl_lazy.sum(
                    subset.is_not_null() & subset.is_not_nan()
                ) >= thresh
            )
        )
    elif how == 'any':
        result = (
            self
            .filter(
                pl_lazy.all(
                    subset.is_not_null() & subset.is_not_nan()
                )
            )
        )
    elif how == 'all':
        result = (
            self
            .filter(
                pl_lazy.any(
                    subset.is_not_null() & subset.is_not_nan()
                )
            )
        )
    else:
        ...

    return self._from_pyldf(result._ldf)


pli.LazyFrame.dropna = dropna
```

For example, if we have the following data:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1": [None, float("nan"), 2, 3],
        "col2": [None, float("nan"), float("nan"), 3],
        "col3": [0.0, float("nan"), 2, 3],
        "col4": [float("nan"), float("nan"), float("nan"), 3],
    }
)
df
```

```
shape: (4, 4)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2 ┆ col3 ┆ col4 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64  │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ null ┆ null ┆ 0.0  ┆ NaN  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ NaN  ┆ NaN  ┆ NaN  ┆ NaN  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2.0  ┆ NaN  ┆ 2.0  ┆ NaN  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3.0  ┆ 3.0  ┆ 3.0  ┆ 3.0  │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

We can use the `dropna` as follows:

```py
list_of_vars = ["col1", "col2"]
threshold = 1
(
    df
    .lazy()
    .dropna(subset=list_of_vars, thresh=threshold)
    .collect()
)

df.to_pandas().dropna(subset=list_of_vars, thresh=threshold)
```

```
shape: (2, 4)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2 ┆ col3 ┆ col4 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64  │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 2.0  ┆ NaN  ┆ 2.0  ┆ NaN  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3.0  ┆ 3.0  ┆ 3.0  ┆ 3.0  │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
>>> df.to_pandas().dropna(subset=list_of_vars, thresh=threshold)
   col1  col2  col3  col4
2   2.0   NaN   2.0   NaN
3   3.0   3.0   3.0   3.0
```

And using the default `how="any"` parameter on the entire LazyFrame:

```py
(
    df
    .lazy()
    .dropna()
    .collect()
)

df.to_pandas().dropna()
```

```
shape: (1, 4)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2 ┆ col3 ┆ col4 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64  │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 3.0  ┆ 3.0  ┆ 3.0  ┆ 3.0  │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
>>> df.to_pandas().dropna()
   col1  col2  col3  col4
3   3.0   3.0   3.0   3.0
```

And here's the result for a `how="all"` on the entire LazyFrame:

```py
(
    df
    .lazy()
    .dropna(how='all')
    .collect()
)

df.to_pandas().dropna(how='all')
```

```
shape: (3, 4)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2 ┆ col3 ┆ col4 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64  │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ null ┆ null ┆ 0.0  ┆ NaN  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2.0  ┆ NaN  ┆ 2.0  ┆ NaN  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3.0  ┆ 3.0  ┆ 3.0  ┆ 3.0  │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
>>> df.to_pandas().dropna(how='all')
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0   NaN   NaN   0.0   NaN
2   2.0   NaN   2.0   NaN
3   3.0   3.0   3.0   3.0
```

For DataFrames, the code simple calls the LazyFrame method.

```py
def dropna_eager(
    self: DF,
    how: str = 'any',
    thresh: int = None,
    subset: str | Sequence[str] = None,
) -> DF:

    result = (
        self
        .lazy()
        .dropna(how, thresh, subset)
        .collect()
    )
    return self._from_pydf(result._df)


pli.DataFrame.dropna = dropna_eager
```

So for example, using non-Lazy mode:

```py
list_of_vars = ["col1", "col2"]
(
    df
    .dropna(subset=list_of_vars, how='all')
)
df.to_pandas().dropna(subset=list_of_vars, how='all')
```

```
shape: (2, 4)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2 ┆ col3 ┆ col4 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ f64  │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 2.0  ┆ NaN  ┆ 2.0  ┆ NaN  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3.0  ┆ 3.0  ┆ 3.0  ┆ 3.0  │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
>>> df.to_pandas().dropna(subset=list_of_vars, how='all')
   col1  col2  col3  col4
2   2.0   NaN   2.0   NaN
3   3.0   3.0   3.0   3.0
```

Comment: Apologies.  I've edited the answer to eliminate the unneeded square brackets inside the `polars.sum`.  Indeed, without the square brackets, we no longer need to use `cast`.  The prior answer works, but this answer takes fewer steps (and is easier to read).

Answer (score 1):

Polars has `is_nan` and `is_not_nan` expressions as well as `is_null`,`is_not_null`.
We need to count the number of NaNs per row, turn this into a column and then filter by this column with the `thresh`

````py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        'col1':[0,float('nan'),2,3],
        "col2":[0,float('nan'),float('nan'),3]
    }
)
list_of_vars = ["col1","col2"]
thresh = 1
df
shape: (4, 2)
┌──────┬──────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ f64  ┆ f64  │
╞══════╪══════╡
│ 0.0  ┆ 0.0  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ NaN  ┆ NaN  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2.0  ┆ NaN  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3.0  ┆ 3.0  │
└──────┴──────┘
(
    df
    .with_column(
df.select(pl.col(list_of_vars).is_nan().cast(pl.Int64)).sum(axis=1).alias("na_count")
 )
    .filter(pl.col("na_count") <= thresh)
)
shape: (3, 3)
┌──────┬──────┬──────────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2 ┆ na_count │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---      │
│ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ i64      │
╞══════╪══════╪══════════╡
│ 0.0  ┆ 0.0  ┆ 0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2.0  ┆ NaN  ┆ 1        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3.0  ┆ 3.0  ┆ 0        │
└──────┴──────┴──────────┘```
````

Comment: Looks great. I'll give it 24h in case anyone stateside wants to chime in

Answer (score 0):

Current best attempt:

```py
var_a, var_b = list_of_vars

df.filter(                            
pl.col(var_a).is_not_null() | (pl.col(var_b).is_not_null())
)
```

Works if I know the number of variables in `list_of_vars` but the number of variables changes on each run