# Polars dataframe drop nans

Tags: python, python-polars

I need to drop rows that have a nan value in any column. As for null values with `drop_nulls()`

```
df.drop_nulls()
```

but for nans. I have found that the method `drop_nans` exist for Series but not for DataFrames

```
df['A'].drop_nans()
```

Pandas code that I'm using:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'A': [0, 0, 0, 1,None, 1],
        'B': [1, 2, 2, 1,1, np.nan]
    }
)
df.dropna()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [polars dropna equivalent on list of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73971106/polars-dropna-equivalent-on-list-of-columns)

Comment: No, sorry. I haven't found my answer there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another definition is: to keep rows where **all** values are not `NaN`

For that, we can use:

- [`.is_not_nan()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.is_not_nan.html#polars.Expr.is_not_nan) to test for "not nan"
- `pl.col(pl.Float32, pl.Float64)` to select only float columns
- [`.all_horizontal()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.all_horizontal.html#polars.all_horizontal) to compute a row-wise True/False comparison
- [`DataFrame.filter`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.filter.html#polars.DataFrame.filter) to keep only the "True" rows

```py
df = pl.from_repr("""
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ B   ┆ C   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ f64 ┆ f64 ┆ str │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 0.0 ┆ 1.0 ┆ a   │
│ 0.0 ┆ 2.0 ┆ b   │
│ 0.0 ┆ 2.0 ┆ c   │
│ 1.0 ┆ 1.0 ┆ d   │
│ NaN ┆ 1.0 ┆ e   │
│ 1.0 ┆ NaN ┆ g   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
""")
```

```py
df.filter(
   pl.all_horizontal(pl.col(pl.Float32, pl.Float64).is_not_nan())
)
```

```
shape: (4, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ B   ┆ C   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ f64 ┆ f64 ┆ str │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 0.0 ┆ 1.0 ┆ a   │
│ 0.0 ┆ 2.0 ┆ b   │
│ 0.0 ┆ 2.0 ┆ c   │
│ 1.0 ┆ 1.0 ┆ d   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

`polars.selectors` has also since been added which provides [`cs.float()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/selectors.html#polars.selectors.float)

```py
df.filter(
   pl.all_horizontal(cs.float().is_not_nan())
)
```

Comment: What if I don't know the number of columns and their types? Without hardcoded `pl.Float32, pl.Float64`

Comment: `pl.col(pl.Float32, pl.Float64)` selects all float columns. Only float columns can contain `NaN`

Comment: Ok, I tried to get a list with all float column names `float_cols` and then use it in `pl.col(float_cols)`. It worked. I will write that answer below.

Comment: `pl.col(pl.Float32, pl.Float64)` already selects the columns without needing to name them e.g. `pl.DataFrame(dict(A=[1], B=[2.0], C=["hi"], D=[3.0])).select(pl.col(pl.Float32, pl.Float64))`

Comment: I see now, you are right.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore! Since polars 0.19.0 you have to use `df.filter(pl.all_horizontal(pl.col(pl.Float32, pl.Float64).is_not_nan())).drop_nulls()`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77017804/polars-valueerror-could-not-convert-value-unknown-as-a-literal

Answer (score 2):

If you have mixed nulls and nans then the easiest thing to do is replace the nans with nulls then use drop_nulls()

```
df.with_columns(pl.col(pl.Float32, pl.Float64).fill_nan(None)).drop_nulls()
```

From inside out:

`pl.col(pl.Float32, pl.Float64)` picks all the columns that are floats and hence able to be nan.

`fill_nan(None)` replaces any nan value with, in this case, None which is a proper `null`

`drop_nulls()` does exactly what it seems like it does.

Comment: It doesn't work for me with this daframe 
`df = pl.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1.0, 1, np.nan, 2],'B': ['1', '1','1','1', None]})`

Comment: @EnesZ I did another edit that simplifies the expression by a lot.

Comment: Yes, it works. The only problem is that the data frame might have hundreds of columns with different types, so hardcoded `pl.Float32, pl.Float64` is not the best solution. Please check my solution where I used a list with float column names.

Comment: I don't know why you are calling it "hardcoded" as though it's relying on some static column names.  Your solution does the same thing, albeit in a more roundabout way having to lookup the column names first.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I thought that `pl.Float32, pl.Float64` means that we want to select two columns or `pl.Float32, pl.Float64, pl.Float64` for three columns, etc. Now I see that it will select all float columns.

Answer (score 0):

As @jqurious suggested but with column names

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        'A': [0, 1.0, 1, np.nan, 2],
        'B': ['1', '1','1','1', None]
    }
)

# get all columns that have a float type
float_col = df.columns
float_col = [c for c in float_col if df[c].dtype in [pl.Float64, pl.Float32]]

df.filter(pl.all(pl.col(float_col).is_not_nan())).drop_nulls()
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

# create a DataFrame with some NaN values
df = pl.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 2, np.nan, 4, 5],
    'B': ['foo', 'bar', 'app', 'ctx', 'mpq']
})

df.to_pandas().dropna()
```

Comment: Nice idea, I could use something like this `pl.from_pandas(df.to_pandas().dropna())` if there is no other solution.

Comment: Don't do this.  Round tripping to pandas is not a good solution.  For toy data you won't notice but bigger data is going suffer from a ton of unnecessary overhead.