# Polars: "ValueError: could not convert value 'Unknown' as a Literal"

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a line of code in polars that worked prior to my most recent update of the polars package to '0.19.0'.  This example ran before:

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        "b": [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        "c": [5, 6, 7, 8, None],})

cols_1 = ["a", "b"]
cols_2 = ["c"]

df = df.filter(pl.all(pl.col(cols_1 + cols_2).is_not_null()))
```

But now raises the error:

```
ValueError: could not convert value 'Unknown' as a Literal
```

Comment: Probably needs to be reported as a bug. You can fix it by using `pl.all_horizontal()`

Comment: The behavior was deprecated in 0.18.8: ` DeprecationWarning: using `all` for horizontal computation is deprecated. Use `all_horizontal` instead.` It was removed as part of 0.19.0.

Comment: That works, thank you!  Just adding the link for future reference:  https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/9752

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer.** I am just summarising the comments of @jqurious and @keraion.

As of the polars release 0.19.0, you'll need to use [dedicated horizontal aggregation functions](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/9752), such as `all_horizontal` or `any_horizontal`.

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "a": [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    "b": [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    "c": [5, 6, 7, 8, None]
})

df.filter(pl.all_horizontal(pl.col(["a", "b", "c"]).is_not_null()))
```

[image]

The horizontal aggregations were introduced in release [0.18.7](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/releases/tag/py-0.18.7) and deprecated in 0.18.8.

Comment: I have tried this solution on my code and I still have the same error, I can't figure out why : 

```
dividends.with_columns(
        (
            pl.all_horizontal(pl.col(dividends.map_rows(
                lambda x: compute_forward_dividend(
                    x[1], 
                    x[2], 
                    x[3], 
                )
            )
        ))).alias("dividendsPerShare")
    )
```

Comment: Edit : i figure it out using this : 
dividends.with_columns(
        (
            dividends.map_rows(
                lambda x: compute_forward_dividend(
                    x[1],
                    x[2],
                    x[3],
                )
            )
        )
    )

Comment: @Oubaluna It would be easier to help if you provided a minimal reproducible example. What is `compute_forward_dividend` here?